# Ошибка C++: write access violation **_Str** was 0xccccccc

Tags: c++, исключения

Почему этот код:

```
struct books {
    char* autor;
    char* title;
};

int main(){
    books katalog[10];
    std::cin >> katalog[0].autor;
    std::cout<< katalog[0].autor << std::endl;
    ...
}
```

Вызывает следующую ошибку?

> An exception was thrown: write access violation **_Str** was 0xccccccc.

Comment: Вы не выдели память для *autor и *title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь вводить и выводить адрес обьекта под которого Вы
  не выделяли память. Вместо указателей можете хранить char[] с
  каким то размером, который можете задать как аргумент шаблона.
  Пример:

```
#include <iostream>

template < size_t n  > 
struct books  {
   static const unsigned k = n;
   char autor[k];
   char title[k];
};

int main()
{
   books<2> katalog[10];
   std::cin >> katalog[0].autor;
   std::cout<< katalog[0].autor << std::endl;
   // для проверки посмотрим на размер books::autor
   std::cout    << sizeof(books<2>::autor);      
   return 0;
}
```

Да, чуть не забыл - в вашем примере наверное есть смысль вводить
  элементы autor, а не autor

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(books<2>::autor); ++i)
     std::cin >> katalog[0].autor[i];
```

Answer (score 3):

У Вас структура, в которой два поля указатели на массив символов. Но память под них не выделяется. Поэтому и происходит вышеуказанная ошибка.

Самый простой, правильный и надежный способ это исправить, это использовать тип `std::string`.

```
struct books {
std::string autor;
std::string title;
}
```

Использовать `char*` нужно только если это пишется для поддержки и си кода (маловероятно), либо так очень сильно захотел преподаватель.

Comment: При замене структуры так как вы написали невозможно ввести значения для katalog[0].autor

Comment: Я указал размер массива  так char autor[100]; char title[100]; и заработало

Comment: Странно, показывайте полный пример, который воспроизводит ситуацию. Или может древний компилятор.

Comment: Бинарный ">>" не найден оператор принимающий левый операнд типа "std::istream"(или приемлемое преобразование отсутсвует)

Comment: что то значит не так у Вас, простой проверочный пример - https://ideone.com/il9VLo - компилируется как нужно.

Comment: `либо так очень сильно захотел преподаватель` — либо указатель не является владеющим.

Comment: Програма работает спасибо!